CC-CEDICT: candidate terms for new definition-request questions
I intend for this to be a "sandbox" or "review space" to keep track of Chinese terms we might consider proposing to add to CC-CEDICT.  My frequent thought process:


That's not in CC-CEDICT; maybe we should add it.
I'll first have to think carefully about that, but I don't have time right now.
A while later... what was that word again?


Also, sometimes it's best not to add a definition, as I found out here: Are "gratitude" and "appreciation" suitable CC-CEDICT definitions for 感激之心?  In future, it'd be nice to know this before posting the question.
Also, I'd be perfectly happy for others to ask questions from what arises.
In my case, my teacher often suggests words to improve my writing.  But I usually don't have time right then to write up a full question with the appropriate research.

Add

合辙押韵

一丝不乱

白费力气

此情不渝

思绪万千

出离愤怒

蛇入鼠出

临危不乱

哈欠连天

心痒难揉

谈婚论嫁

着急忙慌

欲哭无泪

较为密切

东瞧西瞅 from The meaning of 东瞧西瞅?

不远万里 (found on prior HSK6 exam)

不辱使命 (found on prior HSK6 exam)

患难与共 (found on prior HSK6 exam)

说到

坏意

难有

极坏

猛地一惊

另有其人

一扭 and 一扭一扭

了猫 = 乐猫 = "lmao"

微怒 It's in the book 喜欢你，我也是 and says 她微怒地扭头...

雷劈

伪称

差一错误

分润 from What is equivalent of "分润"?

剪贴 (different from 剪贴板)


Modify

梳 seems to have more definitions than just "comb" and "to comb".

出息 definition seems incomplete.

喜悦 is also a noun with measure word 份, e.g. 一份喜悦

痒 is also a noun with measure word 顿, e.g. 一顿痒

废掉 also means something like "give up on life"

但凡 also means "In any case" (I think)

讲究 seems to also be a noun, e.g., 四个讲究.

材料 also means "ingredients" (I think), as in cooking.


Asked

各司其职: What's a suitable CC-EDICT definition for 各司其职?

女娲补天: What is the significance of 女娲补天 beyond its literal meaning "Nüwa mends the sky"?

金口难开: Is 金口难开 an idiom, and if so what would be a suitable CC-CEDICT definition?


